# Number data frame by unique rows in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame in R like this:

```
data.frame('first' = c('A','A','B','C','A','B'),
           'second' = c(1,2,1,1,1,1),
           'third' = c(1,2,1,1,1,3))

  first second third
1     A      1     1
2     A      2     2
3     B      1     1
4     C      1     1
5     A      1     1
6     B      1     3
7     B      2     1
```

Per letter in the first column I want to number the row. For every unique second and third column, the number goes up if the first column is already noticed. If the first column changes, it will go to the other numbering order. So it will end up like this:

```
  first second third group
1     A      1     1     1
2     A      2     2     2
3     B      1     1     1
4     C      1     1     1
5     A      1     1     1
6     B      1     3     2
7     B      2     1     3
```

the columns can be filled with integers or strings. I tried to group them, but that doesn't work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group by the first variable, and `paste` the second and third columns together into a character variable, you can then `match` the resultant vector to its own unique values:

```r
df <- data.frame(first = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 second = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                 third = c(1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group = paste(second, third),
         group = match(group, unique(group)),
         .by = first)
#>   first second third group
#> 1     A      1     1     1
#> 2     A      2     2     2
#> 3     B      1     1     1
#> 4     C      1     1     1
#> 5     A      1     1     1
#> 6     B      1     3     2
#> 7     B      2     1     3
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you! Exactly what I needed